# Inno Setup as bootstrapper for .msi

Tags: installation, windows-installer, inno-setup

I am trying to use Inno Setup to bootstrap a number of prerequisites to my windows installer installation package, and am having pretty good luck with this.

**Now I am wondering if the Inno Setup package can be made so that it doesn't appear in the Add/Remove Programs (ARP) windows option?**

I would like the separate installations to be installed together (each is conditional) but removed separately.

I am installing the install packages into a temp folder generated by Inno Setup, so the actual files are removed at the end of the installation sequence, but the ARP is still showing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

did you try "Uninstallable=false"

Comment: I don't actually want it to be uninstallable - I want the installation to remove itself when it completes running.  Not quite the normal sequence, but it works for a bootstrap application.

Comment: Please reread Tom's answer. Repeat: "Did you try Uninstallable=False"?

This will cause the InnoSetup installer to not create an ARP entry, which I think is exactly what you want, is it not?

Comment: Re-reading my question, yes that is what I asked for, though not exactly what I was looking for.  Accepted.

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured it out!

The registry entry for ARP is added before the installation completes, so I can remove the registry entries during the [run] section and there is no trace of the bootstrap installation left.

Comment: that's utter overkill; just set Uninstallable=False and those entries will not even be created in the first place (see Tom's answer)